# How does this proof that echelon form is unique work?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading the proof from Vector Caluclus, Linear Algebra, and Differential Forms 5th Edition (Hubbard and Hubbard).

The goal is to show that the matrix $\tilde{A}$, which is $A$ in echelon form, is unique. Here's the proof (paraphrased slightly):

For $k\leq m$, let $A[k]$ consist of the first $k$ columns of $A$. The same row operations that change $A$ to $\tilde{A}$ also change $A[k]$ to $\tilde{A}[k]$. We can see that $A[k]$ corresponds to a system of equations
$$x_1\vec{\mathbf{a}}_1+\cdots+x_{k-1}\vec{\mathbf{a}}_{k-1}=\vec{\mathbf{a}}_k 
 \space \space\space\space\space\space\space(1)$$
Equation $(1)$ only depends on $A$, and we know that the system in $(1)$ has no solutions iff the $k$th column of $\tilde{A}[k]$ is pivotal. Thus, $A$ determines the pivotal columns of $\tilde{A}$.

If for some $k$ the system of equations $(1)$ has any solutions, then it has a solution for every value that the variables corresponding to nonpivotal columns among the first $k-1$ columns of $\tilde{A}[k]$ can take. Set these to be $0$. The solution corresponding to that choice uniquely determines the (nonpivotal) $k$th column of $\tilde{A}$.

Thus, the $k$th column of $\tilde{A}$ is unique specified by the system of equations $(1)$, hence by $A$. $\square$

I understand the first part about how $A$ determines the pivotal columns of $\tilde{A}$, and since echelon form requires the pivots to follow a specific set of rules, knowing the pivotal columns will determine where the $1$ is in each column.

However, there are some parts that are a little confusing. First of all, what happens when $k=1$? There would be no "systems of equations" like $(1)$, so I am confused as to how that would be handled.

Next, I can't identify what the penultimate paragraph is proving - isn't the $k$th column already determined after row reduction? What would finding a specific solution with the nonpivotal variables equal to $0$ have anything to do with the values in the $k$th column?